# Why does this trigger not prevent rows from being inserted in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, count, triggers, sum

Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    user_id INT,
    channel_id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE credits(
    user_id INT,
    number_of_items INT CHECK(number_of_items > 0),
    expiration DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, number_of_items, expiration),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE users_items(
    user_id INT,
    item_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, item_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id)
);
```

and here is the trigger I have implemented:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_has_enough_credits_to_monitor_item
BEFORE INSERT ON users_items
BEGIN
   SELECT
     CASE
       WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users_items WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id) >
            (SELECT sum(number_of_items) FROM credits WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id)
         THEN RAISE (ABORT, 'No more items allowed')
     END;
END;
```

I want this trigger to prevent a row from being inserted in the `users_items` table if the user with that ID already has surpassed his credit limit or his credits have expired, however, when I have tested it using [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=8c9a82ba65ee839edc47213ed3c36a2d) fiddle the trigger does not raise an error. Currently the trigger just checks if the number of credits allowed against the number of items added to `users_items` and does not check the date, but I plan on checking the date by adding something like `AND expiration >= datetime('now')` to the trigger to make it look like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_has_enough_credits_to_monitor_item
BEFORE INSERT ON users_items
BEGIN
   SELECT
     CASE
       WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users_items WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id) >=
            (SELECT sum(number_of_items) FROM credits WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id AND expiration >= datetime('now'))
         THEN RAISE (ABORT, 'No more items allowed')
     END;
END;
```

Comment: Change `>` to `>=`, because this is a BEFORE INSERT trigger, so it checks before the new row is inserted.

Comment: @forpas thanks - thats solved it! Do you know why the trigger doesn't work when I add ```AND expiration >= datetime('now')``` to check that the credits had not expired. [This](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=42942e02ef6d4931dd4ab0f0ea85a976) is the fiddle I used to check.

Comment: I'm not sure about the logic you want to apply. You have 2 rows in `credit` for user=1 with expiration = 'now' - 2years. What insertions are you trying to prevent?

Comment: @forpas I want to prevent an insert into ```users_items``` if for that user they don't have enough credits that have not yet expired.

Comment: So, for user=1 in your fiddle since all credits have expired 2 years ago it would be impossible to insert anything in users_tems?

Comment: @forpas Exactly. That's what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok, check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `COALESCE()` for the aggregate function `SUM()` so that when it returns `NULL` because there are no rows satisfying the conditions you get `0` instead and this is comparable to the result of `COUNT(*)` of the 1st subquery:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_has_enough_credits_to_monitor_item
BEFORE INSERT ON users_items
BEGIN
   SELECT
     CASE
       WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users_items WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id) >=
            (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(number_of_items), 0) FROM credits WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id AND expiration >= datetime('now'))
         THEN RAISE (ABORT, 'No more items allowed')
     END;
END;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=e67cbe2c5f5439e18bcc6382cc90d3c3).

Answer (score 1):

From long experience, I want to warn you, don't do this.  Don't use triggers if you can use Declared Referential Integrity (DRI) instead, and don't use triggers for anything other than referential integrity.  In particular, don't use triggers for business rules.

If you don't follow that policy, one day you'll wish you had.

Instead, use a transaction.  For example, write your insert statement to enforce the rule:

```
insert into user_items
select ( ... values ... )
where [user has not surpassed his credit limit and his credits have not expired]
```

Test the rows affected to see if it's zero or one, and display an error if nothing was inserted (meaning the criteria were not satisfied).

In my SQLite applications, I keep an associative array of named "stored procedures", so the SQL never appears in the application logic.  I look up the SQL text by its name in the array, prepare it, and execute it.  That way, if there's a problem with the SQL, there's only one place to look.

As an example of what can go wrong if you use triggers for business rules, consider what happens if two users are inserted at the same time, one that meets the criteria and another that does not.  Do you really want both rows rejected? (Because that's what will happen.)  That's not a use case?  Well, it is: you're writing a rule about the *table*, not what the application will do if the rule is violated.  Tables can be updated outside applications.

Think of it this way: if your rule is violated, your data are still *correct*.  Nothing is inconsistent within the database.  All that's happened is a user has been allowed to exceed some constraint.  You can flag that anytime: a period sweep of the table, a check before play begins, whatever. IOW, if the table somehow is updated by means other than your carefully written INSERT statement, you can always catch the error later, and set things aright.

Comment: What if I don't intend for the table to be updated other than through that particular application?

Comment: That's part of what I'm warning you about.  The trigger applies to the table, not the application. You might *intend* that it never be updated except via the application, but the rule you're creating extends beyond that boundary. You're thereby imposing an unnecessary restriction.  The rule belongs to the application and is best enforced by the application.  That's true for any rule that -- like this one -- does not affect the database's internal consistency.

Comment: I understand - I shall enforce the rule from the application instead. Thanks for the tip!